# In JDO should the DefaultFetchGroup be transitive

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

Totally new to JDO so this could be a simple questions, but I can't find it in the docs.
Suppose I have three persistable classes:

```
 @PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
 public class Foo {

   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
   long id;
   @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
   Set<Bar> bars;
 }

 @PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
 public class Bar {

   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
   long id;
   @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
   SubBar subBar;
 }

 @PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
 public class SubBar {

   @PrimaryKey
   String name;
 }
```

And I have set `javax.jdo.option.DetachAllOnCommit` to `true`.
When I persist/load Foo and close the transaction, should the subBar fields in Bar be also fetched?

Currently if I try to access them on a detached object I get:

```
 javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException: You have just attempted to access field "subBar" yet this field was not detached when you detached the object. Either dont access this field, or detach it when detaching the object.
```

Is the DFG meant to be non-transitive, so that fields of fields aren't fetched by default, or is there some other setting that controls this?
FYI I tried setting the maxFetchDepth for the FetchPlan on Foo, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: `maxFetchDepth` would always limit any fetch, to 1 level, unless it is set. You don't post any actual code of HOW you tried to retrieve an object, or what properties were set, or what state objects were in during this process. What did the LOG say about object state?; that is where you would find your answer.

Comment: You are correct in that the logs are crystal clear, the field on level 2 is not fetched, but I was under no illusion regarding that. I did manage to fetch everything since yesterday by setting the maxFetchDepth after the begin of the transaction (maybe there was a warning when I did that before the begin and I missed it), but I thought it would be possible to set this with the FetchPlan annotation too.

Comment: As already said, without actual code including FetchPlan etc, it is impossible to comment further since people would have to guess